# $overallStatus, $isCMConnected and $isDBConnected is empty when trying to run it only on blue screen

Tags: powershell

This 3 identifier is empty when I'm trying to check them on blue screen below but when running all the script it show this

[image: Connected successfully]

```
`## --- OVERALLSTATUS ---
$overallStatus =''
$isCMConnected =''
$isDBConnected=''

if(!($Output.uri -eq '0') -and !($database.Id -eq '45')){
Write-Host $overallStatus 'Red' -ForegroundColor Red
Write-host $isCMConnected 'Not Connected'
Write-host $isDBConnected 'Not Connected'


}
elseif(!($Output.uri -eq '0')){
Write-Host $overallStatus 'Red' -ForegroundColor Red
Write-host $isCMConnected 'Connected Successfully'
Write-host $isDBConnected 'Not Connected'


}
elseif(!($database.Id -eq '45')){
Write-Host $overallStatus 'Red' -ForegroundColor Red
Write-host $isCMConnected 'Not Connected'
Write-host $isDBConnected 'Connected Successfully'


}
else{

Write-Host $overallStatus -ForegroundColor Green 'GREEN' 
Write-Host $isCMConnected 'Connected Successfully'
Write-Host $isDBConnected 'Connected Successfully'


}`
```

When I'm trying to check the three identifier on blue screen it's empty. Is there something missing on my code?
[image: empty]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Nothing in the code you've shown is inconsistent with the observation of these three variables being empty. You're not checking or assigning those anywhere (except initially to the empty string), you only check `$Output` and `$database`.

Comment: What output are you expecting when you display those variables? The output when executing your script shows ```Connected Successfully``` because you're calling ```Write-Host $isCMConnected 'Connected Successfully'``` - if you call that same command on the command line you'll get the same output as from your script.